# Symfony process executes command but returns failed status

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

By doing

```
public function spawn_queue_process(){
   $command = 'echo hi > find_me.txt';

      $process = new Process($command);
      $process->setWorkingDirectory(base_path());
      $process->start();

      //Just in case :-)
      Log::error($process->getOutput());

      if(!$process->isSuccessful()){
         $exception = new ProcessFailedException($process);
         Log::error('Error on queue call');
         Log::error($exception->getTraceAsString());
      }
   }
```

Even though the file is created, Symfony will throw an exception everytime, rendering useless everything inside `$process` output and making my program freak out about it.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Just for clarification, I got a way more complex command than this running on Linux with no problem, Windows Server however will fail on every single instance of process code.

Comment: Please add details on what the exception is.

Comment: @Hilarion Funny thing, the message that I catch when using the ProcessFailedException is just a stack trace of the execution. Not reason whatsoever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

Make sure you make a (rather weird) work around when executing this type of commands.
Wether you expect the command to be sync or async executed, you gotta wait for the command to be procesed by the server. You can do this by using:

```
$process = new Process($command);
$process->start();

//Block before command is finished sending (still async)
while($process->isRunning()){}

if(!$process->isSuccessful()){
   $exception = new ProcessFailedException($process);
   Log::error($exception->getTraceAsString());
}
```

Otherwise the command will evaluate as still running(when actually its just being sent) and mark it as non completed.